# How about using NodeJS events to implement and update React global state? Good or bad pattern?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

Written in React and NodeJS, I have a `Provider` module and possibly many `Other` modules.

The `Provider` module should provide some `data` to the `Other`: the `data` should be the single source of truth and synched to all `Other` modules.

Here a solution I came up with for a synchronized global state using NodeJS events:

```
// Updater.js module
const emitter = new EventEmitter(); // from NodeJS events
export function on(evt,job) { emitter.on(evt,job); }
export function off(evt,job) { emitter.off(evt,job); }
export function emit(evt,...args) { emitter.emit(evt,...args); }

// Function used to trick React towards re-rendering
function useForceUpdate() {
  const [flip,onFlip] = React.useState();
  return () => onFlip(!flip);
}

export function useUpdater(myevent) {
  const update = useForceUpdate();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const trigger = () => setImmediate(update);  // Will force update React
    emitter.on(myevent,trigger);                 // Register force update on myevent 
    return () => emitter.off(myevent,trigger);   // Unregister
  });
}
```

```
// Provider.js
let data = 'some info';

export function useData() {
  Updater.useUpdater('dataUpdate');
  return data;
}

function compute() {
  ...some computation involving "data"...
  data = 'updated info';
  Updater.emit('dataUpdate');
}
```

```
// Other.js
function Component() {
  const serverData = Server.useData();   // Here I will eventually get the updated data
  return(<h1>serverData</h1>);
}
```

Some explanation:

- The `Updater` module provides an event-like API to update the `Provider`'s `data`. `Updater` create a React state when `Provider` registers `dataUpdate` event. When `Provider` emits on the event, the respective state is "flipped" to force React to trigger a re-rendering.
- The `Provider` provides to `Other` modules a function that make them subscribe to the event for `data`, and return the `data`. Then, when the `Provider` changes the `data`, then `Provider` emits on the event.
- When React triggers the re-rendering, each `Other` module `Component` is re-run, hence each `useData` is re-run, meaning that each `Other` gets the updated `data`.

**Now my questions:** I know that I could rewrite my code into using React `Context` or `Reducer`. But:

- Is my solution worse than the one possibly based on the `Context` or `Reducer`?
- What would be the difference in terms of re-rendering and performance?
- What are the cons of my pattern (because my code works)?

Comment: Do you happen to be aware of websockets API / socket.io?

Comment: `Server` and `Client` are maybe misleading terms. There is a pure React, front-end, application: no communication on the net. I will rename `Server` into `Provider`: the module is there just to provide a global state to all other modules that need the data.

Comment: Then what exactly did you mean talking about *'Node.js events'*?

Comment: If what you need is connecting the state of certain scattered components to global app state, you seem to be re-inventing Redux.

Comment: Well, I know that I could use Redux. But let us say that external constraints do not allow that. I am interested in knowing if this solution is an anti-pattern for React. And whether it would cause slowdowns in rendering. What do you think?

Comment: I think, you may deploy Redux-like approach without Redux itself, using Context API, corresponding hooks and your own home-brew store and actions/reducers. Though your custom implementation will have obvious drawbacks compared to using Redux directly.

Comment: Do you see any cons of my current solution vs. one using Context API? Can you come up with drawbacks of the current solution? Because, if you do, and are major drawbacks, I could try to rewrite it...

Comment: Meaning, is my solution clearly an anti-pattern for React as a collegue of mine has said to me, like "Why do you use events by hand to trigger React rendering rather than use hooks and _react_ on those" ?

Comment: As of *anti-pattern* thing, it is hard to beat someone's arguments, when there're no actual arguments (simply saying something is anti-patter or non-readable, doesn't work). I can't recall any piece of official documentations where it is clearly stated such approach (or its parts) are considered anti-pattern. But I'm not claiming I'm that much deep into React, anyways, so I may be missing something.

Comment: What I may suspect, right off the top of my head: you'll be left on your own with your custom solution (no tutorials, no community support to resolve issues), also, I might suspect, you may risk to miss certain rendering optimizations within React internals. To be entirely sure, I would implement same app with multiple approaches and got them tested up and down.